# Java - Possible to Package some external jars, keep others separate?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm using eclipse to package a program into a runnable jar (Export...>Java>Runnable JAR File). I select the option **Package required libraries into generated jar**, but one external jar can't be packaged.  Is it possible to package the rest of my external jar dependencies while keeping this one outside the main jar?  I'm not looking to use maven or ant or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, just add the library to the `/lib/ext` directory of your JRE.

But this basically means you have to have control of the JRE on the target environment.

Comment: Thank you, I can try it out.  If I build the runnable jar in eclipse it packages everything, so do I have to remove the jar and manifest entry for the one I want to keep separate?  And then place the removed jar in the /lib/ext folder instead?

Comment: Yup, might want to modify the jar file manually, it's just a zip file. Or remove the jar file from the eclipse dependencies and add it to the JRE running eclipse, then build it from eclipse.